# Map Issue in test class

Tags: apex

I am converting a list into two Map's and trying to change one field in second map but its getting changed also in first map

```
List<MeetingInfo__c> meetinginfo_Obj  =  [SELECT Id,Name,MeetingStatus__c,Training__c,Referral__c from MeetingInfo__c limit 1];

Map<Id, MeetingInfo__c> newMeetingMap = new Map<Id, MeetingInfo__c>(meetinginfo_Obj);    
Map<Id, MeetingInfo__c> oldMeetingMap = new Map<Id, MeetingInfo__c>(meetinginfo_Obj); 

 for(id oMeetID: oldMeetingMap.keySet()){
          oldMeetingMap.get(oMeetID).MeetingStatus__c='Completed';
 } 

newhistoryMap{a0Q0p000002YLECEA4=MeetingInfo__c:{Id=a0Q0p000002YLECEA4, Name=MI-0015, MeetingStatus__c=Completed, Training__c=a0O0p000000ccJgEAI, Referral__c=5000p000002wqyOAAQ}}

oldhistoryMap{a0Q0p000002YLECEA4=MeetingInfo__c:{Id=a0Q0p000002YLECEA4, Name=MI-0015, MeetingStatus__c=Completed, Training__c=a0O0p000000ccJgEAI, Referral__c=5000p000002wqyOAAQ}}
```

I tried like this also

```
 Map<Id, MeetingInfo__c> newMeetingMap = new Map<Id, MeetingInfo__c>();    
 Map<Id, MeetingInfo__c> oldMeetingMap = new Map<Id, MeetingInfo__c>();      

 newMeetingMap.putAll(meetinginfo_Obj);
 oldMeetingMap.putAll(meetinginfo_Obj);
```

Please help how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me, but I think there's value in understanding what is happening here.

```
List<MeetingInfo__c> meetinginfo_Obj  =  [SELECT Id,Name,MeetingStatus__c,Training__c,Referral__c from MeetingInfo__c limit 1];

Map<Id, MeetingInfo__c> newMeetingMap = new Map<Id, MeetingInfo__c>(meetinginfo_Obj);    
Map<Id, MeetingInfo__c> oldMeetingMap = new Map<Id, MeetingInfo__c>(meetinginfo_Obj);
```

These Maps are storing the same in-memory sObject instances, because they are created from the same List. There is only one actual `MeetingInfo__c` instance, and the List and both Maps retain references to that single instance.

When you do this

```
 for(id oMeetID: oldMeetingMap.keySet()){
          oldMeetingMap.get(oMeetID).MeetingStatus__c='Completed';
 }
```

you are mutating the single underlying instance. As a result, the contents of `newMeetingMap` and `oldMeetingMap` both reflect the change - they're both storing references to the same sObject instance.

If you don't want that behavior, you need to copy instances rather than storing references to the same instance. This is common to most object-oriented programming languages; it is typical for complex objects to be stored by reference and not deep-copied when they are placed in a collection, like a list or a map.

But I wouldn't recommend you use a clone operation here, because it doesn't really make sense to do so. Your code knows what mutations it is making. You generally won't need to store the "old" version of an sObject, pending further explication of what you're trying to do here. It is common, however, to use a Map to store sObjects that are pending update, so that you do not inadvertently overwrite your own updates or attempt to update the same sObject twice.

Comment: Actually I am trying to write a test class for After update.
If newmap MeetingStatus__c is not equal to oldmap MeetingStatus__c then I will construct a list and will insert that list into another object

Comment: That does not make sense to me. _Why_ are you trying to do this? You do not need to manually construct trigger context variables to test an `after update` trigger.